# Why does Selenium timeout?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I'm attempting to hook together `Selenium.WebDriver` v3.7 (from NuGet), Firefox ESR v52.4.1 (64-bit) and geckodriver v0.19.1 within Visual Studio 2017. Below is my *very* simple test console application.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\geckodriver\0.19.1");
        service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://news.bbc.co.uk");
    }
}
```

The geckodriver directory is *also* added to my Windows 10 `PATH` system environment variable.

However, the instantiation of the `FirefoxDriver` times out. Below is the stacktrace (with a couple of irrelevant details censored):

```
1510233068873   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1510233068878   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:65327
1510233070006   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.qt9HYniTrrCC"

Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:65327/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxDriverService service)
   at Selenium3Stuff.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\x\source\repos\Selenium3Stuff\Selenium3Stuff\Program.cs:line 12
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going on? If I create the `FirefoxDriver` with the `UseLegacyImplementation` option set to true (thus, bypassing geckodriver) then all works fine.

Comment: The timeout occurs because the browser if failing to reply to the driver. This is probably because the version of the driver you are using is not compatible with ESR 52. The recommended minimum version is 55.

Comment: oo... good info @FlorentB. Can you point me to the source of your recommended version info?

Comment: check the comment on release v0.19.0 : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @FlorentB., I was using an unsupported version of Firefox. I moved to using Firefox v56.0 (32-bit) with geckodriver v0.19.1 (32-bit) and all is well. Lesson learnt: pay attention to the versions mentioned on the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:65327/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
```

Moreover when you use **`UseLegacyImplementation`** option set to true (thus, bypassing geckodriver) then all works fine.

In the first case, **`geckodriver`** is trying to listen on port **`65327`** which is somehow occupied. hence the HTTP request cannot be completed and **`System.Net.WebException`** occurs.

The solution would be to stop any other services and keep the ports free for **`GeckoDriver`** to listen. If the problem still persists take a `System Reboot`.

Comment: Yes, I see that the request timed out but I cannot determine why. If I manually point my browser at whatever ephemeral port geckodriver.exe starts listening on I get back a response. So I don't see how it can be an occupied port problem. I've tried this several times, each time a different ephemeral port is used.

Comment: That's correct. `geckodriver.exe` while starting will pick up any random port. We need to isolate the `Test Bed` i.e. `Test Environment` running `Selenium related Tests` from other services so we can avoid any unforeseen obstacles while the `Test Execution` is `In Progress`.

Comment: Okay, but this is my local machine with a trivial program. I still don't understand why the timeout is happening.

Comment: @Mark Check your system if there are any other services running on any other port. You can also ask your System Administrator if they had reserved/blocked any ports as per organization policy. So in that case you have to get the blocked ports released for smooth functioning of your `Selenium Tests`.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Mozilla Firefox Browser v56.0 (32-bit) and the following Nuget packages:

- [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/)
- [Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win32](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win32/).

Was able to automate opening www.google.co.in through Mozilla Firefox using the driver.